# Verifying firebase user verification

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication

When I create a new user I send a confirmation email, I can't track this transition and change the user state from isEmailVerified from false to true, where could I make a mistake?

```
import FirebaseAuth

class User: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let username: String
    let profileImageUrl: String
    let fullname: String
    let email: String
    var stats: UserStats
    var bio: String?
    var blocked : Int
    var reputation : Int
    var isEmailVerified: Bool

    
    var isFollowed = false
    var isCurrentUser: Bool { return Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == self.id}
    
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        self.fullname = dictionary["fullname"] as? String ?? ""
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""
        self.stats = UserStats(followers: 0, following: 0)
        self.blocked = dictionary["blocked"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.reputation = dictionary["reputation"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.isEmailVerified = dictionary["isEmailVerified"] as? Bool ?? false
    }
}
```

```
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: Firebase.User?
    @Published var isAuthenticating = false
    @Published var error: Error?
    @Published var user: User?
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @Published var isEmailVerified: Bool = false

 static let shared = AuthViewModel()
    
    init() {
        userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        fetchUser()
    }
    
    func registerUser(email: String, password: String, username: String, fullname: String, profileImage : UIImage) {
        
        guard let imageData = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }
        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(filename)
        
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { _ , error in
            if let error = error {
                ProgressHUD.showFailed("Failed to upload image: \(error.localizedDescription)", interaction: false)
                print("Failed to upload image \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            storageRef.downloadURL { url, _ in
                guard let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        ProgressHUD.showFailed("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)", interaction: false)
                        print("DEBUG: ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    
                    guard let user = result?.user else { return }
                    
                    // Send email verification
                    user.sendEmailVerification { error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("DEBUG: Error sending email verification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        } else {
                            print("DEBUG: Email verification sent to \(user.email ?? "")")
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                    let data = ["email" : email,
                                "username": username.lowercased(),
                                "fullname": fullname,
                                "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl,
                                "isEmailVerified": false,
                                "uid": user.uid]
                    
                    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid).setData(data) { _ in
                        self.userSession = user
                        self.fetchUser()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowing = false
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel : AuthViewModel
    
    init() {
            addAuthStateListener()
        }
        
    private func addAuthStateListener() {
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            if let user = user {
                let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid)
                
                userRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if let document = document, document.exists {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let isEmailVerified = data?["isEmailVerified"] as? Bool ?? false
                        print("Текущий статус \(isEmailVerified)")
                        
                        // Check if email is verified and update database
                        if user.isEmailVerified != isEmailVerified {
                            userRef.updateData(["isEmailVerified": user.isEmailVerified]) { error in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print("Error updating user document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                } else {
                                    print("User document updated successfully")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if viewModel.userSession != nil {
                if viewModel.isEmailVerified == true {......
```

I tried to find the problem through the debug console, but the console indicates that the document exists, but the value is still false

Comment: You aren't listening for changes

Comment: How long did you wait? The verification of the user's email address happens out of band, so your app won't immediately pick it up. If you do nothing specific, the app will detect it after up to an hour or when you sign out and in again.